# Windows freezing while loading

Tags: windows

For some rather long time i've been having problems running `Win 7` on my old PC. The system randomly freezes on loading screen (Win 7 logo) - nothing happens just displaying the logo waiting forewer to load. What's the most odd as i said it happens totally randomly - once or two the systems loads ok but then say 5x it freezes (after restart or just when turning on the PC).

The important info is that i have some problems whit my HD - i get "`Pri Master Hard Disk: S.M.A.R.T. Status BAD, Backup and Replace Press F1 to Resume`" error during the POST. Can the disk failure affects discribed Win loading problem? Even if so why does it happen so randomly?

My specs:

Win 7 (64bit)
Mainboard: MSI H55-G43

Comment: Considering the OS is installed in the disk, of course it failing affects everything.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem with your HDD is probably the cause of the freezes.

It's random because a hard drive don't fails necessarily immediately: The disk may have some bad sectors and others that are still in working condition.